# IOS 11 shows question mark (?) Character instead of Single quote (') or Double Quote ("")

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios11

I am working on Xamarin.iOS application. And found due to updating the device with IOS 11, result shows shows question mark (?) Character instead of Single quote (') or Double Quote ("") in Text.

Any one found such issues?

Comment: Those characters are in Windows Latin-1, **"Windows-1252"**, and not in Latin-1, **"ISO-8859-1"** - though _browsers_ interprete ISO-8859-1 as Windows-1252. Maybe HTML is involved? Or the source text comes from Windows (MS Word typically).

Comment: Seems a bug from iOS 11. I have gone through various references and found as Apple has added Smart Punctuations feature in these release which is not recognised by application. Not sure why .. but found a work around: as Turn Off Smart Punctuations in Settings/General/KeyBoard. But waiting for fix. Please let me know if anyone finds the fix.

Comment: Very helpful comment @JJBHATT, you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a work around: as Turn Off Smart Punctuations in Settings/General/KeyBoard.

Comment: FYI - I was having the same issue in iOS 15.5.  I was sending data between an iOS device (source) and Android device (destination) using sockets.  I turned off the setting as listed above.  Re-typed my text on iOS and then re-pulled the data to Andoird and it worked correctly.  I wish there was a programmatic way to to disable this for my app but at least I have a solution.